# Fatal error in ../deps/v8/src/api.cc, line 1197 when gulp watch

Tags: node.js, gulp, rebuild

gulp watch throws the following error. Please help. When I raised an issue on the gulp github repo, they suggested me to rebuild native modules. How do I rebuild modules? I installed all packages through npm.

```
#
# Fatal error in ../deps/v8/src/api.cc, line 1197
# Check failed: !value_obj->IsJSReceiver() || value_obj->IsTemplateInfo().
#

==== C stack trace ===============================

    0   node                                0x00000001008abaa1 v8::base::debug::StackTrace::StackTrace() + 19
    1   node                                0x00000001008aa803 V8_Fatal + 213
    2   node                                0x0000000100140e1e v8::Template::SetPrivate(v8::Local<v8::Private>, v8::Local<v8::Data>, v8::PropertyAttribute) + 0
    3   fse.node                            0x0000000103ff6ba3 fse::FSEvents::Initialize(v8::Local<v8::Object>) + 197
    4   node                                0x00000001007f8f6e node::DLOpen(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&) + 864
    5   node                                0x00000001001677fe v8::internal::FunctionCallbackArguments::Call(void (*)(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&)) + 416
    6   node                                0x00000001001b479c v8::internal::MaybeHandle<v8::internal::Object> v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::HandleApiCallHelper<false>(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::HeapObject>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::HeapObject>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::FunctionTemplateInfo>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::BuiltinArguments) + 871
    7   node                                0x00000001001b3db2 v8::internal::Builtin_Impl_HandleApiCall(v8::internal::BuiltinArguments, v8::internal::Isolate*) + 276
    8   ???                                 0x000035fa5760437d 0x0 + 59349324022653
    9   ???                                 0x000035fa579a1794 0x0 + 59349327812500
Illegal instruction: 4
```

node -v
v8.0.0

npm -v
5.0.3

gulp -v
CLI version 3.9.1
Local version 3.9.1

Source code: https://github.com/SKempin/reactjs-tmdb-app/

Comment: It looks like you just need to update you native dependencies. `npm rebuild` worked for me when I encountered this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alright. I found answer to this from Stephen Kempin.

I was not running an LTS version of node. I downgraded my node to v6.11.2

Check 
https://github.com/nodejs/LTS/ for latest lts version
https://www.abeautifulsite.net/how-to-upgrade-or-downgrade-nodejs-using-npm for changing your node version

After you're done, cd into your project directory and do npm rebuild then do gulp/gulp watch.

This worked for me.

Posting this so this might help other noobs like me.

Comment: Thats not obvious, I appreciate it!!

Comment: worked for me installing current LTS of 6.12.3 thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Saw this same issue on OSX and fixed it using `npm update`.